# Clear byte Data voice stream?

Tags: c#, sockets

Tell me how clear byte data get from network? ex:

```
 public void OnRecievedData(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                Socket sock = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                try
                {
                    int nBytesRec = sock.EndReceive(ar);
                    if (nBytesRec > 0)
                    {
                        sound.PlayReceivedVoice(buffer);
                     //   Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        SetupRecieveCallback(sock);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        sock.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }
```

I want to delete the previously received data. thanks

Comment: Tell me meaning you have clear is? Dude, i have no idea what you mean - and this is not you are bad in english, you jsut use random terms. What do you think "clear byte data" is?

Comment: when I receive data without deleting what earlier, ram will increase continuously. I want to delete the previously received data. applications such as voice chat

Comment: For a start, take out the exception handler - that could be hiding any errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to delete the previously received data.

Learn how garbage colleciton works. THIS part is NOT a memory leaak, it may simply be delayed freeing because the GC sees no need to free memory.

If you have a memory leak, it is somewhere else and there are tools to find it (MemProfiler is what I use).